# Как исправить запрос к БД MySQL?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть такой запрос:

```html
SELECT NULL, u.id, u.user_login, ((SUM(r.amount)+io.amount_value)*0.28), ((sum(r.amount)+io.amount_value)*0.28+SUM(r.amount)+io.amount_value), 'RUB', (DATE(ul.expire_time) - CURDATE()), start_time, now(), ul.expire_time, 'no'
FROM ihc_orders io 
JOIN users u ON io.uid = u.id
JOIN uap_affiliates ua ON io.uid = ua.uid
JOIN uap_referrals r ON ua.id = r.affiliate_id
JOIN ihc_user_levels ul ON ul.user_id = u.id
WHERE io.status='Completed' AND r.status ='2' AND ul.status='1'
GROUP BY io.uid
```

Проблема в том, что выводятся только пользователи у которых есть запись в uap_referrals (на данный момент 10), но туда заносятся не все (всего 34). Как исправить запрос к БД Mysql чтобы записи выводились по всем пользователям? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Некоторые [INNER] JOIN заменить на LEFT JOIN. И, возможно, перенести условия отбора в условия связывания.

Comment: @Akina Спасибо. Так выводятся записи по всем.